# php.ini.default not finding new path to cloudfusion on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: php, macos, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to follow along with a book on Amazon EC2 and it says to include a new file path in php.ini in the etc folder to the cloudfusion sdk. So I uncommented the path variable in php.ini.default and set the new path to be:

```
include_path = ".:/php/includes:/Users/john/cloudfusion"
```

but yet when I try running my php script inside a folder named amazon, it keeps giving me the error:

```
Warning: require_once(sdk.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/john/amazon/create_bucket.php on line 26

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'sdk.class.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/john/amazon/create_bucket.php on line 26
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: And file `/Users/john/cloudfusion/sdk.class.php` exists? Or is it in some sub-folder?

Comment: Ow, re-reading your post, you need to move `php.ini.default` to `php.ini` most likely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't read `php.ini.default`, it just defaults to the values in it internally, to make sure your changes are read, you can copy that file to `php.ini` and edit your values.

Alternatively you can use https://www.php.net/ini_set function to modify your include path on-the-fly. You need to use `ini_set` before the actual `require_once`.

Comment: And a green checkmark goes to you kind friend. Worked perfectly. I appreciate the help!